# How can I change my display to 24 or 32 bit in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, display-settings, f.lux

I have a Dell Inspiron 1501 and I'm trying to use [f.lux](http://www.stereopsis.com/flux/) with ubuntu, but when I start it I get `Sorry, we only support 24/32-bit displays right now.` How can I change my display to 24 or 32 bit? I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `DefaultDepth 24` under `Section Device` in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.

Comment: This is all I have in /etc/X11/
app-defaults   rgb.txt  xorg.conf.failsafe  Xsession.options
cursors    X   Xresources       XvMCConfig
default-display-manager  xinit   Xsession       Xwrapper.config
fonts    xkb   Xsession.d

Comment: @officespace Try copying xorg.conf.failsafe to xorg.conf, restart X server and check what happens

Answer (score 0):

Try [redshift](http://jonls.dk/redshift/), it doesn't need any particular display depth.